# Recursion Draws

Tags: java, user-interface, recursion, graphics, geometry

See Above for description

However my code is adding circles to the array in incorrect colours:

I have a Color baseColor, which contains a variable int baseGreen. This int is reduced during each recursive call, with the intention of changing the type of green for each set of 3 circles.

If anyone is able to hazard a guess as to why this is happening I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Color simply follows your recursion path. With each size you first you go all the way to the left, then center, then right. Instead of tracking your color independently you may want to make it a function of `rad`.

Comment: As you reduce "rad" in each recursion, you just need to make a darker shade for your colour and pass that on. Just like you reduce "rad" by 1/3, you increase shade and use the new colour shade to make the 3 createCircles() call.

Comment: Cheers for the reply, could you please demonstrate how I should implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tracking base color is unnecessary as you are passing it into your method.

this is a simple way of make the color progressively darker

```
public void createCircles(int x, int y, int rad, Color parentColor){
    Circle myCircle = new Circle(x, y, rad, parentColor);
    ...
    if(!(rad<1)){
        ...
        Color myColor = parentColor.darker();
        createCircles(x - (2*rad), y, rad/3, myColor);
        createCircles(x, y, rad/3, myColor);
        createCircles(x + (2*rad), y, rad/3, myColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented it now (see above) but I still get an incorrect representation of the circles. Have I done it correctly?

Comment: Color myColor = parentColor;???? You should be calling darker() and create a new darker color to be used for the 3 callss to createCircles().